# Using b trees in a database

Tags: database, algorithm, b-tree

I have to implement a database using b trees for a school project. the database is for storing audio files(songs), and a number of different queries can be made like asking for all the songs of a given artist or a specific album.

The intuitive idea is to use on b tree for each field *( songs, albums, artists, ...)*, the problem is that one can be asked to delete any member of any field, and in-case you delete an artist you have to delete all his albums and songs from the other b trees, keeping in mind that for example all the songs of a given artist don't have to be near each other in the b tree that corresponds to songs.

My question is: is there a way to do so *(delete the songs after a delete to an author has been made)* without having to iterate over all elements of the other b trees? I'm not looking for code just ideas because all the ones I've come up with are brute force ones.

Comment: Yes, that's what you are supposed to do. Delete a song means delete from all the trees. Delete an artist means delete all his songs. No shortcuts here. You don't have to search in other trees as the song record should have pointers to all the tree nodes.

Comment: In your problem, you probably have fields and tables. If you normalize your schema, you will end up with several tables. You need to keep that in mind when designing your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my understanding and may not be entirely right.

Typically in a database implementation B Trees are used for indexes, so unless you want to force your user to index every column, defaulting to creating a B Tree for each field is unnecessary. Although this many indexes will lead to a fast read in virtually every case (with an index on everything, you wont have to do a full table scan), it will also cause an extremely slow insert/update/delete, as the corresponding data has to be updated in each tree. As I'm sure you know, modern databases for you to have at least one index (the primary key), so you will have at least one B Tree with a key for the primary key, and a pointer to the appropriate node.

Every node in a B Tree index should have a pointer/reference to the full object it represents.

Future indexes created would include the attributes you specify in the index, such as song name, artist, etc, however will still contain the pointer/reference to the corresponding node. Thus when you modify, lets say, the song title, you will want to modify the referenced node which all the indexes reference. If you have any indexes that have the modified reference as an attribute, you will have to modify the values in that index itself.

Unfortunately I believe you are correct in your belief that you will have to brute-force your way through the other B Trees when deleting/updating, and is one of the downsides of using alot of indexes (slowed update/delete time). If you just delete the referenced nodes, you will likely end up with pointers to deleted objects, which will (depending on your language) give you some form of a NullPointerException. In order to prevent this they references will have to be removed from all the trees.

Keep in mind though that doing a full scan of your indexes will still be much better than doing full table scans.

Comment: the scan of btrees will ultimately depends on the database schema and relationship between tables: if the row being modified holds indexed fields, then each impacted btree will have to be updated. In case of a field being a foreign key in another table (and if the feature is supported), then some consistency check will have to be performed.

Comment: You are correct, I was stating that every tree will have to be updated on the assumption that the B Trees were simply indexing based on a different primary key, and still contained all attributes in the index (I believe this was what the asker was planning to do, however I may be wrong)

Comment: I understand that, and your answer is correct imho. I just wanted him to see that he might have to consider this aspect of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: My idea is to keep one BTree for each field. Each BTree has as key the field and the song-row, and when i delete an Author (e.g.) i must find all his songs and delete them in all remaining BTree's. But i dont know whether or not this is optimal. The deletion is the main problem. Is there another way??? I think it's very slow, but if that is the only option i am stuck.